# Can't syncronize SQL Server and SQL Server CE with wcf

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm trying to syncronize between SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server CE with a WCF service library, but I always get error like

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {EC413D66-6221-4EBB-AC55-4900FB321011} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I'm trying to copy in windows app, it's just work fine. any suggestions?

Here's my code :

```
[OperationContract]
string ExecuteSync(string tableName, SyncDirectionOrder direnction);

public string ExecuteSync(string tableName, SyncDirectionOrder direnction)
{
        try
        {
            SqlCeConnection clientconn = new SqlCeConnection(SetConnectionCE.ConnectionStringCE);
            //var vcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCon"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SetConnection.ConnectionString);

            SyncOrchestrator syncorchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();

            // set local provider of orchestrator to a ce sync provider associated with the 
            // productsscope in the synccompactdb compact client database
            StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();
            string[] splitstring = null;
            splitstring = tableName.Split('|');

            foreach (string _tableName in splitstring)
            {
                syncorchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlCeSyncProvider(_tableName + "_Scope", clientconn);
                syncorchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(_tableName + "_Scope", con);
                syncorchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;

                // subscribe for errors that occur when applying changes to the client
                ((SqlCeSyncProvider)syncorchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed);

                // execute the synchronization process
                SyncOperationStatistics syncstats = syncorchestrator.Synchronize();

                bld.Append("\n Start Time :" + syncstats.SyncStartTime);
                bld.Append("\n total changes uploaded :" + syncstats.UploadChangesTotal);
                bld.Append("\n total changes downloaded :" + syncstats.DownloadChangesTotal);
                bld.Append("\n complete time :" + syncstats.SyncEndTime);
                //OutputText ot = null;
                //ot = new OutputText { Output = bld.ToString() };
            }

            return bld.ToString();

            // set the direction of sync session to upload and download
        }
        catch (SyncException ex)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            //sb.Append ("\n Error Number : " + ex.ErrorNumber.ToString () );
            sb.Append("\n Message Error : " + ex.Message);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you installed the SQL Server 2005 synchronization components on the client machine? For example, sqlmergx.dll and sqldistx.dll need to be present and registered with regsvr32.

Comment: no, i haven't register, in fact i dont know where are those dll locate

Comment: your using Sync Fx, you don't need those DLLs. have you installed Sync Fx on your WCF service side? if you have them installed, have you made sure that you built your service with the target platform matching the Sync Fx platform? (e.g., x86 Sync Fx, build your service target platform to x86 as well)